# SQL - Intersections

Tags: sql, intersection

I have table like below:

```
|Group|User|
|  1  | X  | 
|  1  | Y  |
|  1  | Z  |
|  2  | X  |
|  2  | Y  |
|  2  | Z  |
|  3  | X  |
|  3  | Z  |
|  4  | X  |
```

I want to calculate intersections of groups: 1&2, 1&2&3, 1&2&3&4.
Then I want to see users in each intersection and how many of them are there.
In the given example should be:

```
1&2     -> 3
1&2&3   -> 2
1&2&3&4 -> 1
```

Is it possible using SQL?
If yes, how can I start?

On a daily basis I'm working with Python, but now I have to translate this code into SQL code and I have huge problem with it.

Comment: What's the database? I would assume PostgreSQL if you don't say.

Comment: It's in Clickhouse. But it'll be in BigQuery soon.

Comment: I think if I handle it in any DB, I'll do it in another.

Comment: It would be easy with a recursive CTE, I believe neither Clickhouse nor BigQuery supports it

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL you can use `JOIN` or `INTERSECT`. Example with `JOIN`:

```
select count(*)
from t a
join t b on b.usr = a.usr
where a.grp = 1 and b.grp = 2
```

Then:

```
select count(*)
from t a
join t b on b.usr = a.usr
join t c on c.usr = a.usr
where a.grp = 1 and b.grp = 2 and c.grp = 3
```

And:

```
select count(*)
from t a
join t b on b.usr = a.usr
join t c on c.usr = a.usr
join t d on d.usr = a.usr
where a.grp = 1 and b.grp = 2 and c.grp = 3 and d.grp = 4
```

Result in `3`, `2`, and `1` respectively.

**EDIT** - You can also do:

```
select count(*)
from (
  select usr, count(*) 
  from t
  where grp in (1, 2, 3, 4)
  group by usr
  having count(*) = 4 -- number of groups
) x
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=eeab9084adc2661637bddba67c9d95bd).

Comment: What If I have more groups? Like 15-20.
Can be there any other way to solve it?

Comment: Great! It looks good! 
Can I add loop or sth, so I don't need to write this 15-20 times?
Cuz I also have to modify tuple with groups:  where grp in (1, 2, 3)
and It'll be frustrating.

Comment: @Joe , you can create a parameterized query passing it the list of groups in a form of array or csv string. If you have a problem creating a query like that you'd better ask another question.

Comment: It's something wrong with this approach.
I made it twice in 2 different ways: 
- length(arrayIntersect(groupUniqArray, )) in CH and
- using pandas in Python.
Both ways had same results, but different than yours.

Comment: Ok. I got it.
I had to drop duplicates or change the condition from having count(*) = 4 to  having count(*) >= 4.